# JSON array convert to Python array

Tags: python

[{
data: "31/05/2010 19:39:00",
empresa: {
codigo: 1
},
descricao: "teste",
tipoEvento: "RHYTHM VARIATION"
},
{
data: "31/05/2010 18:15:00",
empresa: {
codigo: 1
},
descricao: "teste ",
tipoEvento: "RHYTHM VARIATION"
}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an overly simple question, and I would encourage you to read the documentation in the future, but nonetheless:

```py
import json
your_str_data = r'''
[{"data":"31/05/2010 19:39:00","empresa":{"codigo":1},"descricao":"teste","tipoEvento":"RHYTHM VARIATION"},{"data":"31/05/2010 18:15:00","empresa":{"codigo":1},"descricao":"teste ","tipoEvento":"RHYTHM VARIATION"}]
'''
jdata = json.loads(your_str_data)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(jdata)
```